# Component background color in angular 2

Tags: css, angular

I have a Home component inside it I have a carousel component. I would like to apply background color of home as Gray and background color of the carousel as blue.

I am unable to apply a background color to the body tag of Home component.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 is all about modularity so it purposefully adds a css scope to all of your styles in a component so that a parent's component's styles don't bleed through and affect the way that a child component looks. Thats why all of your components have that weird attribute that looks like this: `_ngcontent-c0`

If you look at the css that was generated for your component, you'll also notice that this tag has been added to all of your styles: `h1[_ngcontent-c0]`

So your Home and Carousel components would need their own styles:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'home',
   template: `<body>
                <carousel></carousel>
              </body>`,
   styles: ['body { background-color: gray; }']
}) 

@Component({
   selector: 'carousel',
   template: `<div id="carousel_body">
                 <!-- carousel stuff here -->
              </div>`,
   styles: ['#carousel_body{ background-color: blue; }']
})
```

The other alternatives you have are:

1. Make the styles global by putting them in a css file that is referenced by your index.html in the traditional manner
2. Use a special selector such as :host or /deep/ to override the css scoping mechanism (/deep/ is deprecated)
3. You can set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on all of your components which disables the css scoping, but in my opinion, this defeats much of what makes angular great.

Each of these options are described in greater length [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

[Here's an example on plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/vbjBcCuXlaeeSVN4xC7i?p=preview)